# sum of columns using ng-table angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using angular/ng-table to plot numerical data in tabular form. 
I am not able to figure out how to bring in a row at the end of my table which shows sum of all the values of each column. 
I can compute the data on the server side and present it in the UI. 
But is there a way to achieve this in ng-table/ng-grid?
Any help will be appreciated.

thanks

Comment: What of summing in the controller using the data retrieved from the server?

Comment: you can access your data array. You just need to do it in JS in the controller and show it in the template.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You mean something like this?

```
<table ng:init="stuff={items:[{description:'gadget', cost:99},{description:'thing', cost:101} ]}">
<tr>
    <th>Description</th>
    <th>Cost</th>
</tr>
<tr ng:repeat="item in stuff.items">

    <td>{{item.description}}</td>
    <td>{{item.cost}}</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>{{stuff.items.$sum('cost')}}</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: @ErichBSchulz this is an Angular function, deprecated after https://code.angularjs.org/0.9.9/angular-0.9.9.min.js

Comment: ah thanks - that is why I couldn't find it! maybe worth updating the anser to save others wasting time?