# Trigger an action immediately on insert in a HTML table

Tags: javascript, html, real-time, onchange

I have a simple contenteditable HTML table:

```
<div contenteditable>
     <h2 id="titolo">Input</h2>
         <table id="input">
             ...
         </table>
</div>
```

Now, I have to create some functions, like the sum of the values of a column calculated in the last cell of that column, or the copy of an inserted value in all the following cells of that cell in its row.

I know that I can calculate all these things with JS, calling functions by pressing some buttons. However, is there some way to make these functions immediate, in the sense that when I insert a value, changes are made immediately, in real time?

Comment: You are looking for *Data Binding* which is not available in vanilla javascript ES5. Have a look on a framework that supports databinding  like AngularJS or Backbone

Comment: Just to add to @deadlock comment see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19164911/sum-of-columns-using-ng-table-angular

Comment: Thanks, i'll check angularJS. But in addition to my question, what if i need to replicate these changes immediately in other HTML pages in the same folder?

Comment: @JimmyPage are you expecting this table to have text box or something? Or is it that you are expecting when you add an additional row to the table it is to do something? Can you explain what is the structure/design of your table for it to accept inputs?

Answer (score 1):

```
$( ".target" ).change(function() {
    console.log('the value change');
});
```

This function is called when the target value changes.

Comment: How to bind this function to a cell?

Comment: Change the  $(".target"') by your class or id.
$("#input tr td") i think this selector work.